# Smooth choppy imageline for PHP GD graphs

Tags: php, graph, gd

I cannot get smooth lines for this graph. I have tried anti aliasing, increasing the image and I found a few smoothing functions on php.net but the results are not consistent, and sometime result in choppy lines themselves.

I UPDATED THE CODE BELOW AND SHOWED/COMMENTED THE CHANGES USED TO FIX THE ISSUE

**The Code:**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");

$Values=array(rand(40,80),rand(40,100),rand(10,50),rand(80,160),rand(30,100),rand(40,120),rand(280,360),rand(20,80),rand(10,80),rand(40,120),rand(180,260),rand(40,160),rand(550,700),rand(480,600),rand(240,340),rand(480,600),rand(240,340));
$imgWidth=500;
$imgHeight=200;
$grid=25;
$graphspacing=0.05;

while (list($key, $val) = each($Values)) {
    if($val>$max){
        $max=$val;
    }
}

for ($i=0; $i<count($Values); $i++){
    $graphValues[$i] = $Values[$i] * (($imgHeight*(1-$graphspacing))/$max);
}

// use imagecreatetruecolor instead of imagecreate
$image=imagecreatetruecolor($imgWidth, $imgHeight);

// added antialiasing
imageantialias($image, true);

// had to force a white bg
$bgColor = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($image , 0,0 , $bgColor);

$colorWhite=imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$colorGrey=imagecolorallocate($image, 192, 192, 192);
$colorBlue=imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 255);

imageline($image, 0, 0, 0, $imgHeight, $colorGrey);
imageline($image, 0, 0, $imgWidth, 0, $colorGrey);
imageline($image, $imgWidth-1, 0, $imgWidth-1, $imgHeight-1, $colorGrey);
imageline($image, 0, $imgHeight-1, $imgWidth-1, $imgHeight-1, $colorGrey);

// Create grid
for ($i=1; $i<($imgWidth/$grid); $i++) {
    imageline($image, $i*$grid, 0, $i*$grid, $imgHeight, $colorGrey);
}
for ($i=1; $i<($imgHeight/$grid); $i++) {
    imageline($image, 0, $i*$grid, $imgWidth, $i*$grid, $colorGrey);
}

if($imgWidth/$grid>count($graphValues)){ 
    $space=$grid; 
} else { 
    $space = $imgWidth/(count($graphValues)-1);
}

for ($i=0; $i<count($graphValues)-1; $i++) {
    imageline($image, $i*$space, ($imgHeight-$graphValues[$i]), ($i+1)*$space, ($imgHeight-$graphValues[$i+1]), $colorBlue);
}
```

// added smooth filter
imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_SMOOTH, 15);

```
imagepng($image);//,NULL,9);
imagedestroy($image);

?>
```

**The result is (best I have gotten yet):**

before

[image]

after

[image]

Cheers.Bo

Comment: Just to have a working example, init `$max=0` is mssing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `imagecreate` i would advice using `imagecreatetruecolor` then add `imageantialias` to that image .... ( Can't see any imageantialias  in your code )

There always always a difference

I would advice you to look at examples at http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageantialias.php

I hope this helps

Thanks

:)

Comment: I think that was a subtle distinction I overlooked.. ill look into it!

Comment: I altered the code above to show the working fix. After the fact I added a SMOOTH filter which made it even better.